# Postman throwing error for POST and PUT request: RestAPI C# Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, postman, rest

I have coded RestAPI with .NET . I am using Postman to test the API.
It is giving me successful http request for GET and DELETE. But throwing error for PUT and POST request.

Below are the codes I am using to create RestAPI.

Code: Player.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnityRestAPI.Contracts
{
    [JsonObject, Serializable]
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code: PlayersController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UnityRestAPI.Contracts;

namespace UnityRestAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PlayersController : Controller
    {

    private static List<Player> Players = new List<Player>()
    {
        new Player
        {
            Id = 1,
            FullName = "Michael Jordan",
            Score = 1000
        },
        new Player
        {
            Id = 2,
            FullName = "Steve Jobs",
            Score = 2000
        },
        new Player
        {
            Id = 3,
            FullName = "Carton John",
            Score = 3000
        },
    };


    // GET api/players
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return Json(Players);
    }

    // GET api/players/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        Player player = Players.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        return Json(player);
    }

    // POST api/players
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Player newPlayer)
    {
        Players.Add(newPlayer);
        return Json(Players);
    }

    // PUT api/players/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public JsonResult Put(int id, [FromBody] float newScore)
    {
        Player player = Players.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        player.Score = newScore;
        return Json(player);
    }

    // DELETE api/players/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Player player = Players.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        Players.Remove(player);
    }
}
}
```

RestAPI GET request in Postman:
[Successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsoSo.png)

Postman Error for POST request in Postman:
[Input not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1iKW.png)

Comment: in the Post man Error you chosen RAW on the right there is a blue dropdown list on the right it says text 
just change it to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a RAW Type issue
try to Change the following
[image]

To

[image]

Comment: Hi IbraHim, Thank you for the reply. It solved the both POST and PUT request error in Postman.